# C# Ninject Parameter based Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-extensions

I am using Ninject to inject dependencies.
I have the following class structure :

```
public interface IClass
{
}

public class Class: IClass
{
 public virtual void Method(Object context)
 {
  --------
 }
}   

public class Class1: IClass
{
 public override void Method(Object context)
 {
  --------
 }
}

public class Class2: IClass
{
 public override void Method(Object context)
 {
  --------
 }
}
```

`context` contains - HasBilling , HasPayment  properties along with other more properties.

`Method()` is invoked by using factory pattern:

```
public interface IClassFactory
    {
        IClass CreateClass();
    }

_classFactory.CreateClass().Method(....)
```

So when the parameter `HasBilling` equals to `true` then i have to invoke `Method()` of `Class1` implementation, similarly if `HasPayment` equals to true, `Method()` of `Class2` implementation must be called.

Using Ninject Binding, I tried these bindings, but neither one worked:

```
Bind<IClass>().To<Class1>().When(x => x.Target.Member.Name.Contains("HasBilling").Equals(true));
```

Tried this, but no luck:

```
Bind<IClass>().To<Class1>().WithMetadata("HasBilling", true);
```

Please can some one help me with what bindings needs to be set to call `Class1` , `Class2` method(`Method`) based on a parameter value(`HasBilling,HasPayment`) .

Many Thanks In Advance,

Thanks,
WH

Answer (score 0):

If your `context` is necessary to determine which concrete type to load then you'll need to pass it either to your concrete classes or to the factory.  AFAIK there's no way for Ninject to examine your call chain to say "method X is going to be called, so I need to use that information to determine which concrete class to use".

If you change your factory, this problem because very simple:

```
interface IClassFactory
{
   IClass CreateClass(Object context)
}

class ClassFactory : IClassFactory
{
   IClass CreateClass(Object context)
   {
      if (context.HasBilling)
          return new Class1();

       // default case
       return new Class2();
   }
}
```

Then you would consume with:

```
IClassFactory classFactory; // injected
object context;

classFactory.CreateClass(context).Method();
```

---

An alternative is to use a proxy pattern.  `IClass` stays the same, do away with `IClassFactory`.  Instead you use a proxy:

```
public class ClassProxy : IClass
{
    void Method(Object context)
    {
       if (context.HasBilling) 
          new Class1().Method(context);
       else
        //etc
    }
}
```

In your kernal you'd wire this up as:

```
kernel.Bind<IClass>().To<ClassProxy>();
```

You'd also need to make sure your implementations are NOT bound to `IClass` in the kernel.  (So make sure there's you **DO NOT** have `kernel.Bind<IClass>().To<Class1>()`.

If you want to take advantage of DI for your implementation classes, however, you could make them self bindable (`kernel.Bind<Class1>().ToSelf()`) and then your `ClassProxy` could take them as dependencies:

```
class ClassProxy : IClass
{
    private readonly Class1 _class1;    
    private readonly Class2 _class2;

    public ClassProxy(Class1 class1, Class2 class2){
       _class1 = class1;
       _class2 = class2;
    }

    void Method(object context)
    {
         if (context.HasBilling)
             _class1.Method(context);
    }
```